# Query Multiple tables randomly with limit

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating an android application using an SQL database with multiple tables. I need to select rows randomly from some or all the tables (there are around 8).

I have tried the following query, but it is giving me an "IndexOutOfBoundsException" in Java, the query is only selecting data from the "core" table and ignoring the "parking" table. Where have I gone wrong? I have read about the JOIN function, does it apply here?

```
        c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM core, parking" + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + rounds, null);
```

All tables use the same column structure, but the Column ID overlaps for each one (e.g. for 8 tables, there are 8 "1" column IDs) .The Column IDs are not used in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there must be a column which exist in both table ie ID.. 
then write as

```
SELECT * FROM core as c, parking as p where c.ID=p.ID " + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with regards to c.ID=p.ID, what if one table has more rows than the other table??

Comment: no prob it will work , but there should be one common column b/w them to make  relation ie c.id=p.id ..only

Comment: It isn't working, I am now getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException: "Invalid Index 0, size is 0." 

I have also tried the code in SQLite Manager. The code only works on columns where the ids (or another equal text) for both tables are equal.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM core UNION ALL SELECT * FROM parking" <--- It works, but the "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT x" doesn't work when added on. Ideas?